# Laravel sanctum & nuxt/auth-next request to auto fetch user is not sent anymore

Tags: laravel, nuxt.js, laravel-sanctum, nuxt-auth

I'm using nuxt auth with laravel sanctum, the login works but the request to get the authenticated user is not sent anymore !
[successful login proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jDvLy.png)

And this is my nuxt.config.js

```js
axios: {
        baseUrl: process.env.API_URL,
        credentials: true,
    },
  
    auth: {    
        strategies: {
      'laravelSanctum': {
        provider: 'laravel/sanctum',
        url: process.env.API_URL,        
        endpoints: {
            login: { url: '/api/login'},
            user: { url: '/api/user', method: 'get', propertyName: false },
          },
          autoFetchUser:true,
          tokenRequired: true,
          tokenType: "Bearer"      
            },
      
    },
        redirect: {
            login: '/auth/login',
      logout: '/auth/login',
      callback: '/auth/login',
      home: '/'
    },
    localStorage: false
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

I was using  `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost`
in all my urls, that's why somehow it was not sendind the /api/user request !

Client .env

```
PORT=3000
HOST=localhost
BASE_URL=http://localhost:3000
API_URL=http://localhost:8000
```

Server .env

```
APP_URL=https://localhost:8000
SESSION_DOMAIN=localhost
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=localhost:3000
```